# Is there an issue tracker for Google Drive Realtime API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am facing a bug with [Realtime API of Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/) and I like to know if there is an issue tracker where I can check if that issue is registered and eventually fill a new one.

Comment: p.s. what's the issue?

Comment: reported at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/drive/report-a-problem/KwfrTauAy9g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no official bug trackers for the Google Drive service.

There is this page, which lists the known issues encountered using Google Drive :

```
http://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs
```

And this other one that links to Google Drive service's forum, where yo can actually *report* an issue (look at the proposed categories):

```
https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/drive
```